# Facing issues after using Magento 2.3.3 p1

Tags: php, magento, magento2, magento-2.3

Using Magento 2.3.3 p1. Applied this security patch to Magento 2.3.3.

Now we are facing issue to save Magento configuration for specific module with options. Throwing 503 error. It was working fine for Magento 2.3.3. Is this issue with Magento 2.3.3 p1 ?

system.xml

```
<group>
...
...
...
<field id="selectourexp" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="0" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Our Integration</label>
                    <source_model>Namespace\Module\Model\System\Config\Ourexp</source_model>
                    <backend_model>Namespace\Module\Model\System\Config\Ourbackendcall</backend_model>
                    <depends>
                        <field id="ourflag">enabled</field>
                    </depends>
                </field>
            </group>
```

Ourexp.php

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Module\Model\System\Config;

class Ourexp implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return [
            [
                'value' => \Namespace\Module\Model\Call\Layer::FRONTEND_JAVASCRIPT,
                'label' => __('Option 1')
            ],
            [
                'value' => \Namespace\Module\Model\Call\Layer::BACKEND_API,
                'label' => __('Option 2')
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

Not defining anything related to options in Ourbackendcall.php

Comment: Can you please share your apache error log please? so we can really see what's going on

Answer (score 0):

Try seeing if the file maintenance.flag exists in your Magento root directory.

If you see this file, remove it and the error will go away.

Answer (score 0):

Enable Magento debug mode to see errors on configuration save

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
bin/magento setup:config:set --enable-debug-logging=true
bin/magento cache:flush
```